# Spring WebFlux & Mockito: How to verify the stream was consumed and participating handlers were invoked

Tags: java, mockito, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm experimenting with [Spring on Reactive stack](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html). I'm relatively new to reactive streams in Java. I'm tyring to wrap my head around how to test and verify object collaboration in reactive streams. I'm using *spring-test* and *reactor-test* libraries for TDD testing.

Here is the flawed test

```
@Test
void givenWeatherService_whenGetWeather_thenPublishWeatherAsync() throws Exception {
    
    Mono<Sample> mono = service.updateWeatherFeed();
    
    RecordedRequest request = server.takeRequest();
    assertThat(request.getMethod()).isEqualTo("GET");
    assertThat(request.getPath()).isEqualTo("/api/weather");
    
    StepVerifier.create(mono)
        .assertNext(sample -> {
            verify(publisher, times(1)).publish(sample);
            verify(sensorRepository, times(1)).insertSample(sample);
        }).verifyComplete();
}
```

And here is the service method implementation

```
public Mono<Sample> updateWeatherFeed() {

    // Uses WebClient to return the stream
    Mono<Sample> mono = getWeather();
    
    mono.doOnNext(sample -> {
        sensorRepository.insertSample(sample);
        samplePublisher.publish(sample);
    }).subscribe();
    
    return mono;
}
```

The *StepVerifier* hangs with the following log:

```
10:21:01.827 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [id: 0x81e9584a, L:/127.0.0.1:62510 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:62479] Channel cleaned, now 1 active connections and 1 inactive connections
```

What is the correct way to verify the stream was consumed and participating handlers were invoked in order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is probably here:

```
public Mono<Sample> updateWeatherFeed() {

    // Uses WebClient to return the stream
    Mono<Sample> mono = getWeather();
    
    mono.doOnNext(sample -> {
        sensorRepository.insertSample(sample);
        samplePublisher.publish(sample);
    }).subscribe(); // <--- right here
    
    return mono;
}
```

You see you are subscribing and thus consuming the stream. If you look in the api for [Mono#subscribe](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#subscribe--) you can see that it returns a disposable. Which means it has been consumed, and is ready to be disposed.

Reactive streams consists of a `producer` and a `consumer`. The `consumer` `subscribes` to the `producer` and starts `publishing`. Whomever initiates the call is the `consumer` hence should be the one to `subscribe`.

In your case, the test is the one initiating the call, so the test is the `consumer` and should be the one `subscribing`.

If we look at the [StepVerifier#create](https://projectreactor.io/docs/test/release/api/reactor/test/StepVerifier.html#create-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-) we can see that it takes a `Publisher` and a publisher is a non/consumed `Mono` or `Flux`, not a `Disposable`.

So how do we fix this, well you need to remove the `subscribe()`

```
public Mono<Sample> updateWeatherFeed() {
    return getWeather().flatMap(sample -> {
        sensorRepository.insertSample(sample);
        samplePublisher.publish(sample);
        return sample;
    });
}
```

Then you dont need the `StepVerifier` since you are returning a `Mono` which is just one item. If you where testing a `Flux` you can use the `StepVerifier` to "step through" your `Flux`.

```
// Set up mocks and such

@Test
void doTest() throws Exception {

    final Service service = new Service(publisherMock, sensorRepositoryMock);
    final Sample sample = service.updateWeatherFeed().block();
    
    // Assert Sample
    assertEquals(sample, ...);

    // Verify mocks
    verify(publisherMock, times(1)).publish(sample);
    verify(sensorRepositoryMock, times(1)).insertSample(sample);
}
```

It's been a while i did this but i wrote this by free hand so i hope you at least the the gist of it.